# Display box2 from behind box 1

Tags: html, css

i want to display my box2 from behind box1.

i can use `position: relative;` into `.box1`.

but, i got another problem when im using that `position` into my project.

**How to display** `.box2` **from behind** `.box1` **without set** `position: relative;` **into** `.box1`**?**

```css
.main {
  height: 100%;  
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
}

#box2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 79px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: 110px;
  background: black;
  heigth: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.slideInLeft {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div id="box1">
</div>
<div id="box2" class="animated slideInLeft">
Some text 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: why don't you put your box 2 inside box1 so that it will come over it.

Comment: it's not just about jsfiddle, I equate the case as it is on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change z-index to -1

```css
.main {
  height: 100%;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
}

#box2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: 110px;
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div id="box1">
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class="animated slideInLeft">
    Some text
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ahh . hahah .. i try `z-index: 1` .

Comment: Okay work here, thanks.
But can you help me? why (box2) not show up when i input into my program? is there a conflict with other scripts?

Comment: Because I use z-index to other element?

Comment: it's work on jsfiddle when im adding z-index, but not work in my program.